# Hadoop example not working after installed

Tags: java, hadoop, protocol-buffers

Hi I recently installed hadoop 2.7.2 in a distributed mode, with the namenode being `hadoop` and datanode being `hadoop1` and `hadoop2`. When I do `yarn jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar pi 2 1000` in bash, it gives me error message like:

```
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 1000
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "benji/192.168.1.4"; destination host is: "hadoop":9000; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:99)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:498)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.<init>(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.<init>(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$1.parsePartialFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$1.parsePartialFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2290)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:200)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:241)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:253)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:259)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.parseDelimitedFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:3167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1085)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:979)
```

And if I do `hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar pi 2 1000`, it gives error message like:

```
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 1000
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "hadoop/192.168.1.4"; destination host is: "hadoop":9000;
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:773)
... blabla ...
```

Notice the weird mysterious difference between the two error messages lies in local host name (one is `benji/192.168.1.4` and the other is `hadoop/192.168.1.4`). I do `start-dfs.sh`, and `start-yarn.sh` before the `yarn jar ...`, all look well.

**I will be very much appreciate if anyone can help to figure out the problem.** Here are contents of some configuration files:

- `/etc/hosts` file (`benji` is the non-hadoop account on the master computer):

  ```
  192.168.1.4     hadoop benji

  192.168.1.5     hadoop1

  192.168.1.9     hadoop2
  ```
- `/etc/hostname` file:

  ```
  hadoop
  ```
- `~/.ssh/config` file:

  ```
  # hadoop1
  Host hadoop1
  HostName 192.168.1.5
  User hadoop1
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/hadoopid

  # hadoop2
  Host hadoop2
  HostName 192.168.1.9
  User hadoop2
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/hadoopid

  # hadoop localhost
  Host localhost
  HostName localhost
  User hadoop
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/hadoopid

  # hadoop
  Host hadoop
  HostName hadoop
  User hadoop
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/hadoopid
  ```
- `core-site.xml` file:

  ```
  <configuration>

  <property>

    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>

    <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hadoopdata/tmp</value>

    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>

  </property>

  <property>

  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>

  <value>hdfs://hadoop:9000</value>

  </property>

  <property>

    <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>

    <value>131072</value>

  </property>

  </configuration>
  ```
- `hdfs-site.xml` file:

  ```
  <configuration>

  <property>

  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>

  <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hadoopdata/dfs/namenode</value>

  </property>

  <property>

  <name>dfs.datanode.du.reserved</name>

  <value>21474836480</value>

  </property>

  <property>

  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>

  <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hadoopdata/dfs/datanode</value>

  </property>

  <property>

  <name>dfs.replication</name>

  <value>1</value>

  </property>

  <property>

  <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>

  <value>hadoop:9001</value>

  </property>

  <property>

  <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>

  <value>true</value>

  </property> </configuration>
  ```

Could anyone help on this issue? Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I figured out part of the problem. I did `jps` and found datanode and namenode was not running. After `netstat -an | grep 9000` and `lsof -i :9000` I found that another process is listening the port `9000`. The namenode was able to run after I changed `fs.defaultFS` from `hdfs://hadoop:9000` to `hdfs://hadoop:9001` in the `core-site.xml` file, and `dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address` from `hadoop:9001` to `hadoop:9002` in `hdfs-site.xml`. The `protocol-buffer` error message disappeared after this change. But the datanodes were still not running according to the result of `jps`.

The datanode log file shows something weird happening:

```
... blabla ...
2016-05-19 12:27:12,157 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop/192.168.
1.4:9000. Already tried 44 time(s); maxRetries=45
2016-05-19 12:27:32,158 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to se
rver: hadoop/192.168.1.4:9000
... blabla ...
2016-05-19 13:41:55,382 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2016-05-19 13:41:55,387 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
... blabla ...
```

I do not understand why the datanode tries to connect to the namenode on port 9000.

Comment: Where is the `127.0.0.1  localhost` in your `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: I commented it out previously because it is not used in the distributed mode. I have just added `127.0.0.1 localhost` back but the error messages are the same.

Comment: Are you able to do passwordless authentication to all the slave machines from the master

Comment: Yes. I am able to do passwordless authentication to all the slaves.

Comment: I'm not sure why you removed that line (or why you need benji to be the same hostname as hadoop), but the error seems to be related to a hosts file misconfiguration. Is that the same hosts file on all the nodes?

Comment: Adding or removing that line does not affect the error message.

Comment: See my update1 for the solution of the old problem and the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a configured Hadoop package installed in all your slaves, only changing the `fs.defaultFS` in namenode to `hdfs://hadoop:9001` but not the datanodes will yield the datanodes try to connect to `hdfs://hadoop:900` as it's stated in their `core-site.xml`.

Comment: I have `scp`ed the configure file from master to slave. The error is not because of this.